# getiing RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while reading pickel file in pandas or by pickle package?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pickle, google-colaboratory

I'm creating pickle file from pandas dataframe for the memory concern I'm saving it as pickle file and in that machine I can be able to read and parse the pickle file but when I downloaded that pickle file tried to use those pickle file in google colab(I'm doing it because to utilize the GPU) I can be able to load the pickle file but when I try to parse It I'm getting the following error.
[image]

when I tried to print that data frame I'm getting the following error
[image]

I'm saving pickle file from data frame with the following code

```
for store in df['store_id'].unique():
    store_data = df[df['store_id']==store]
    store_data.to_pickle(f'{store}.pkl')
    gc.collect();
```

why I'm getting these error, please help me on resolving these things

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem when I try to open a pickle file (which is saved in python 3.6) with python 3.7. I solved the problem when I switch back to the 3.6 version.

Comment: Do you have any explanation for this?